# Maximum call stack size exceeded when dispatching an action from onEnter

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying to dispatch an action when entering a page but for some reason it results in an infinite loop of the action being dispatched.

Here is my code :

```
 const routes = (store) => {
   const test = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
     Promise.resolve(store.dispatch({type: 'test'})).then(callback());
   };

   return (
     <Route path="/" component={App}>
       <IndexRoute component={LoginPage}/>
       <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} onEnter={test}/>
     </Route>
   );
 };
```

I've tried replacing the dispatch with a simple console.log and this doesn't happen.
It's only when I try to dispatch from onEnter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was using immutablejs and had not properly configured react-router-redux.

I had:

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, { selectLocationState(state) {
    return state
      .get('routing')
      .toJS();
  }});
```

I am now using instead:

```
const createSelectLocationState = () => {
  let prevRoutingState,
    prevRoutingStateJS;
  return (state) => {
    const routingState = state.get('routing'); // or state.routing
    if (typeof prevRoutingState === 'undefined' || prevRoutingState !== routingState) {
      prevRoutingState = routingState;
      prevRoutingStateJS = routingState.toJS();
    }
    return prevRoutingStateJS;
  };
};

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {selectLocationState: createSelectLocationState()});
```

and it's working correctly.

Source: https://github.com/sjparsons/react-router-redux-immutable